# Save the KEY only once when a user inputs either the key or value from a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

So I am trying to receive the Key from the dictionary when a user inputs the key itself or the value of the key in python.

```
dict= {'1':'one','2':'two','3':'three','4':'four','5':'five'}

userinput = input('Please choose from the dictionary : ')    
for key, values in dict.items():
    if userinput == key or values:
        print (key)
```

> So I was thinking the when the user entered 'two' to be '2' or when user entered '5' to be '5'

But rather I am getting the key it self

Comment: print(dict[key]) - also, don't call your dict "dict" that's an internal python type.

Comment: Also, invert the dictionary, since that's what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, we cannot compare variables like you have shown `if x == y or z`.
Instead try this

```
dict= {'1':'one','2':'two','3':'three','4':'four','5':'five'}

userinput = input('Please choose from the dictionary : ')    
for key, values in dict.items():
    if userinput == key or userinput == values:
        print (key)
```